# PostgreSQL Sort

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, collation

I have a sort problem in PostgreSQL with below data:

```
name
-----
@CF
@CG
CD
CE
```

I used `select name from table order by name`, the result as below:

```
name
-----
CD
CE
@CF
@CE
```

It seems that Postgres just ignores the special character `@` and sorts the left string. However, I'd like it sorted like this:

```
name
-----
@CF
@CG
CD
CE
```

Searching the internet didn't help. I hope someone here could give a suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Use [PostgreSQL's collation support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) to tell it you want a particular collation.

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS VALUES ('CD'),('CE'),('@CF'),('@CE');
```

You can force byte-wise collation using:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY column1 COLLATE "C";
```

The `"C"` collation is a byte-wise collation that ignores national language rules, encoding, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just add that to the order by clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(name,1) = '@' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, name ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Your undisclosed [collation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html) setting obviously ignores the `@` character for sort order. Either switch to another collation as [suggested by @Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20866085/939860). Or, if you want to stick to your collation for the rest of the string, add a special case for leading `@`.

In Postgres you can order by `boolean` values directly. Default order is `FALSE`, `TRUE`, `NULL`.

```
ORDER BY name !~~ '@%', name
```

`!~~` being the Postgres shorthand for `NOT LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT name
      FROM table 
     ORDER BY name WHEN LEFT(name, 1) = '@' 
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name
```