# PostgreSQL incorrect sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 9.3.3 and I have a table with one column named as title (character varying(50)).

When I have executed the following query:

```
select * from test
order by title asc
```

I got the following results:

```
#
A
#Example
```

Why "#Example" is in the last position? In my opinion "#Example" should be in the second position.

Comment: Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d819d/1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I tested it on SQL Server 2008 R2, #Example is in second row as expected

Comment: What is the data type of the `title` column ?

Comment: Wow, adding a `desc` to Gordon's sqlfiddle produces '#Example', 'A', '#'

Comment: Oracle 11.2 returns the same wrong order

Comment: @Glenn: Because `ASC` is the default order direction

Comment: If you change '#' to '_' or '*' the error will stay; so there's nothing special with '#' symbol

Comment: I just tried this with a temp table on PostgreSQL 9.2 and the sorting order was correct ('#', '#Example', 'A'). What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865552/postgresql-sort)

Answer (score 25):

Sort behaviour for text (including `char` and `varchar` as well as the `text` type) depends on the *current collation* of your locale.

See previous closely related questions:

- [PostgreSQL Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20865552/398670)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/21006868/398670

If you want to do a simplistic sort by ASCII value, rather than a properly localized sort following your local language rules, [you can use the `COLLATE` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html)

```
select * 
from test
order by title COLLATE "C" ASC
```

or change the database collation globally (requires dump and reload, or full reindex). On my Fedora 19 Linux system, I get the following results:

```
regress=> SHOW lc_collate;
 lc_collate  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8
(1 row)

regress=> WITH v(title) AS (VALUES ('#a'), ('a'), ('#'), ('a#a'), ('a#')) 
          SELECT title FROM v ORDER BY title ASC;
 title 
-------
 #
 a
 #a
 a#
 a#a
(5 rows)

regress=> WITH v(title) AS (VALUES ('#a'), ('a'), ('#'), ('a#a'), ('a#')) 
          SELECT title FROM v ORDER BY title COLLATE "C" ASC;
 title 
-------
 #
 #a
 a
 a#
 a#a
(5 rows)
```

PostgreSQL uses your operating system's collation support, so it's possible for results to vary slightly from host OS to host OS. In particular, at least some versions of Mac OS X have significantly broken unicode collation handling.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that when sorting *Oracle* as well as *Postgres* just *ignore* **non alpha numeric chars**, e.g.

```
  select '*' 
   union all
  select '#' 
   union all
  select 'A'
   union all
  select '*E'
   union all
  select '*B'
   union all
  select '#C'
   union all
  select '#D'
order by 1 asc
```

returns (look: that DBMS *doesn't pay any attention* on prefix before 'A'..'E')

```
  *
  #
  A
  *B
  #C
  #D
  *E
```

In your case, what Postgres actually sorts is

`''`, `'A'` and `'Example'`

If you put `'#'` in the *middle* od the string, the behaviour will be *the same*:

```
  select 'A#B'
   union all
  select 'AC'
   union all
  select 'A#D'  
   union all
  select 'AE' 
order by 1 asc
```

returns (`#` ignored, and so `'AB', 'AC', 'AD'` and `'AE'` actually compared)

```
  A#B
  AC
  A#D
  AE
```

To *change* the comparison rules you should use **collation**, e.g.

```
  select '#' collate "POSIX"
   union all
  select 'A' collate "POSIX"
   union all
  select '#Example' collate "POSIX"
order by 1 asc
```

returns (as it required in your case)

```
  #
  #Example
  A
```

Comment: But this sorts '#A', 'C', '#B' with hashes first.

Comment: @Glenn: Yes, '#' ignored and '#A', 'C', '#B' are sorted as they should be '#A', '#B', 'C' (since 'A' < 'B' < 'C')

Comment: This depends on the collation of the database. When I run your statement on my local database (using UTF8 and a german collation) get the result in this order: `#,#C,#D,*,*B,*E,A`